# I can't enable full content assist in Eclipse for cpp archives

Tags: c++, eclipse, content-assist

I have checked all fields in Eclipse/Preferences/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced but I still can't view any **default proposal** while executing Ctrl+Space, even if my code recognizes if statements or include's(I have installed C/C++ Development Tools).

For instance I would like to be able to view all proposals while typing

"`lastTrackableId = trackable(Ctrl+Space)`" instead of `getId();`  in the above code

`lastTrackableId = trackable.getId();`

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Window/Preferences/C/C++/Editor/Content Assist/Advanced -> select the needed proposals.
if it still doesnt work, check another type of eclipse. (Actually, I have Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, and I imported the needed files)

other option: go to Window/Preferences/C/C++/Editor/Content Assist/ and Restore Defaults and restart eclipse.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.I reinstall my CDT for Eclipse and after that it didn't work again.